# How are the textfields customized with MUIX version 6

Tags: material-ui, mui-x

We are migrating MUIX v5 to v6 & need to upgrade the DateRangePicker component. The documentation suggests to use slotProps to customize, but need help on how to customize the both textfields using new syntax. In other words how is startProps & endProps applied here using the MUIX v6 syntax.
[image]